# How can i remove horizontal scroll bar  wordpress admin editor

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is screen shot : http://d.pr/i/QhkF

My theme is : http://www.templatemonster.com/wordpress-themes/37712.html

Any idea?

Comment: So you want to fix the content area to certain width, isn't it?

Comment: what is the problem?see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the content area of an editor of wordpress, then the only way way to do this by adding the custom css to your default template.

To do this go to your default template and add the below line to your `functions.php`.

suppose i have given a name for my custom css file like `test.css`.

```
add_editor_style('test.css'); //in functions.php
```

and then create a file named test.css (or whatever) in your theme directory and put this line of code inside it:

```
html .mceContentBody {
        max-width: 400px !important; // whatever improbable size you want
}
```

Comment: Yes it's working.. But i  need 100% width in all screens.. if i did fix the  content are to certain width, smaller screens displays scrollbar. (i hope i was explain... sorry for my bad english)

Comment: It sounds like the text is not wrapping to its container.Also, text won't wrap unless it contains spaces or hyphens, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Other wordpress page don't have horizontal scroll all screen resolution, only vertical scroll is going bigger..
Small screen shot : http://d.pr/i/JS2Y
Big  screen shot : http://d.pr/i/Kj1G
i need this, all screen see only vertical scroll ? :(

Comment: `@user1719993` The scroll-bar seems to be caused by something generated by java-script, i.e. very likely by a plugin.Have you tried to deactive all plugins?and then re-activated them one by one to see which one is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you personalize your site you'll need to go to site styling > custom CSS and add this script :

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

It will enable your horizontal scroll.